# How to refer a value to another column in another table using PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am using PHPMyAdmin.
i have two tables. SoundValues and Measurements.

I used an SQL statement on the table Soundvales to calculate an average value of its columns, but I want that value to show in a column in the Measurements table. Usually I refer foreign keys by using PHPMyAdmin "relation function" but this is not a simple foreign key situation.  I want the average value to show in a column in the Measurements table.
How do I do that using PHPMyAdmin?

Thank you

Comment: Please provide the 2 table schema, and the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what is in the rest of your Measurements table, you can just create a view rather than a table for this, for example:

```
CREATE VIEW measure_avg AS
SELECT AVG(column_to_average)
FROM Soundvalues
```

Then you can refer to measure_avg as you would a table and select the average as you need it. I'm not sure that it's possible to put aggregate functions as a column in an actual table.